# Processing JSON using Swift JSONDecoder

Tags: json, swift, struct, codable, jsondecoder

Here is my JSON I am trying to parse

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "layout": "Y",
    },
    {
      "layout": "A",
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to filter out the layout types that are not supported. I am using the JSONDecoder to to convert the JSON data into structs but I am having an issue processing the rows. I am attempting to convert each row using let row = try? rowContainer.decode(Row.self) but I can figure out how to move to the next one if it fails unless I decode it to an empty struct. I tried just decoding it to a Dictionary but it won't except Any for the value field.

```
enum RowType: String, Codable {
    case a = "A"
    case b = "B"
}

public struct Page: Codable {

    let rows: [Row]

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        // Get Container
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // Create Result Array
        var rowResult: [Row] = []

        // Get Rows Container
        var rowContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .rows)

        // Process Rows
        while !rowContainer.isAtEnd {

            // Create Row
            if let row = try? rowContainer.decode(Row.self) {
                rowResult.append(row)
            }
            else {

                // Increment Row Container
                _ = try rowContainer.decode(Empty.self)
            }
        }

        // Set Result
        rows = rowResult
    }

    // Used For Unsupported Rows
    struct Empty: Codable {}
}

public struct Row: Codable {
    let layout: RowType
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a different approach.

Create a temporary struct with the `layout` string value

```
public struct RawRow: Codable {
    let layout: String
}
```

In `Page` first decode `rows` to `RawRow` and then `compactMap` the array to `Row`. It filters all items whose `layout` value cannot be converted to the enum

```
public struct Page: Codable {
    let rows: [Row]

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let rowData = try container.decode([RawRow].self, forKey: .rows)
        rows = rowData.compactMap {
            guard let rowType = RowType(rawValue: $0.layout) else { return nil }
            return Row(layout: rowType)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason in this situation to use the type alias Codable rather than Decodable?

Comment: @Marcy No, there's none. Actually `Decodable` is sufficient. I just copied&pasted the structs.

Comment: Thank-you @vadian for your clarification.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was doing to in my code above but I was trying to avoid having an extra struct like that but thank you for your reply

Comment: Isn't `Empty` an extra struct as well? 

Comment: Yeah thats what I am trying to get rid of

Comment: hii @vadian need one help from u, i m not getting answer to question plz check this question and provide solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281675/how-to-create-top-navigation-like-reddit-app-in-swift-3?noredirect=1#comment89560371_51281675